# Code-first relation to aspnet_users in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, relation

How can I link a table created with the Code-First approach to the default Users table of ASP.NET? I am working with Entity Framework 4.3.1 and MVC3 in C#.

The project I am working on is meant for an organisation that organizes tournaments. When they create a tournament, a new user has to be created linked to that tournament so that when this user logs in, he can only work with that particular tournament.

Any idea how to make this relation with Code-First?

Thanks in advance,
Bart

Comment: example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/184133/Using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Code-First-with-an-exis

Answer (score 0):

I would deploy the tables to your database for reference, then copy them into models. Just make sure to get all the relationships correct for the FK, etc. You should then be able to have EF deploy the database and use the built-in membership tables.

If you ever upgrade to MVC4 with SimpleMembership, check out this example: http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model